# Determine available terminal emulators

Tags: linux, terminal, terminal-emulator

How can I determine the available terminal emulators on a linux machine?

A while ago I saw an answer on a SE exchange site, likely this one, that gave a directory where Linux typically keeps files related to the different installed terminal emulators. I don't know the terminology for exactly what sort of files these were (something like "terminfo"? does that make any sense?) but the names of these files seemed to be the values I could set TERM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The directory in question turned out to be:

/usr/share/terminfo/

Related reading I found informative:

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/111746/why-do-we-need-so-many-terminal-emulator-packages-and-what-is-their-use

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/108410/is-it-correct-to-set-the-term-variable-manually